# Java Calculator with classes

Tags: java

OK so i have been working on a calculator with classes(To play with classes but a function) and when ever I run it all i get back is zero no matter what I type in or say to use for the operator. Here is my code:

Main class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
  //numof = number of numbers in array
  // numarrays = the array for user input
 // finial = finial number aka the answer

public class Calculator {
public static double finial;    
/**
 * @return the finial
 */
public static double getFinial() {
    return finial;
}



/**
 * @param numof the finial to set
 */
public static void setFinial(double finial) {
    finial = numof;
}

public static int numof;    
/**
 * @return the numof
 */
public static int getNumof() {
    return numof;
}



/**
 * @param numof the numof to set
 */
public static void setNumof(int numof) {
    numof = numof;
}


public static double[] numarrays;
/**
 * @return the numarrays
 */
public static double[] getNumarrays() {
    return numarrays;
}



/**
 * @param numarrays the numarrays to set
 */
public static void setNumarrays(double[] numarrays) {
    numarrays = numarrays;
}







@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to my calculator, in this calculator you can add, subtract or multiply");
    System.out.println("For the next step I need to know how many numbers you would like to input? ");


    int numof;  
    Scanner numofnums= new Scanner(System.in);
    numof = numofnums.nextInt();
    Calculator.setNumof(numof);



    System.out.println("So next you are going to input the numbers");


    double[] numarrays = new double[numof];
    for (int k=0; k < numof; k++){
        System.out.println("Please enter number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        numarrays[k] = input.nextDouble();

    }
    Calculator.setNumarrays(numarrays);

    System.out.println("Please enter what you would like to do with these numbers add,subtract,avg,multiply");
    Scanner OP = new Scanner(System.in);
    String OPerator= OP.next();
    if (OPerator.equals ("add")){
        Add.adding();


    }
    else if (OPerator.equals ("subtract")){
        subtract.subtracting();


    }
    else if (OPerator.equals ("multiply")){
        multiply.multiplying();

    }
    else if (OPerator.equals ("avg")){
        avg.avging();

        }
        System.out.println("The answer is " + Calculator.getFinial());





}
}
```

here is the add class:

```
    public class  Add extends Calculator {

public static void adding() {
    double finial = 0;


for (int h = 0; h < Calculator.getNumof(); h++){
    finial  = finial + Calculator.getNumarrays()[h];


}
Calculator.setFinial(finial);
}
}
```

I do have three more classes but it is just operator classes let me know if you need them

Comment: This looks like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using one, you can step through your code line-by-line as it executes and observe the runtime behavior and variable values.  This will allow you to see specifically where the logic isn't doing what you expect and to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look shows some significant basic issues. For example, in a basic setter, like:

```
public static void setFinial(double finial) {
    finial = numof;
}
```

from your code, what you most likely intended was

```
public static void setFinial(double paramFinial) {
    finial = paramFinial;
}
```

If your static variable and your parameter have the same name, you can't access both. The compiler will think you're talking about the parameter. Also, be careful that your setter is using the parameter paramFinial instead of the probably unintentional reference to `numof`.

It would be a lot easier to read the rest of your code if you would comment what `finial`, `numof`, and your other variables represent.

Comment: Really quick how do you use this if the main class does not like it not being static

Comment: Of course. Sorry about my mistake. You can't use 'this' with static variables. Instead, you need to use distinct names so the compiler knows which variable you're talking about. I have updated my answer.